# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la cola de ediciones sugeridas para aprobar modificaciones por ortografía?

Tags: soporte, ediciones-sugeridas, revisiones

Desde que me incorporé a SO en Español me he encontrado con preguntas que carecen principalmente de ortografía, algunas de las cuales me he detenido a corregirlas y darles una presentación que una comunidad como SOes merece.

Una vez que modifico o corrijo esas preguntas son revisadas y aprobadas por pares, y mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo, de igual forma, revisar y aprobar preguntas que son modificadas por ortografía o se ponen en el formato debido identificando referencias, segmentos de código, listas etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los usuarios con una reputación de 1000 tienen acceso (mientras estemos en beta).
Las revisiones se realizan desde [**/review**](//es.stackoverflow.com/review) (el enlace también está en la barra superior del sitio).

**Reputación para las colas de revisión:**

- A partir de **350** de reputación (o 500 en sitios graduados), ya obtuviste acceso a 2 colas de revisión:
  [**Respuestas tardías** y **Primeras publicaciones**](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)
- Desde que tengas una reputación de **500** (o 3k en sitios graduados), tendrás acceso a las colas de revisión:
  [**Votos de cierre** y **Votos de reapertura**](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)
- Una vez que tengas **1000** de reputación (o 2k en sitios graduados), podrás editar directamente las publicaciones sin que sean revisada por pares y adicionalmente tendrás acceso a las colas:
  [**Ediciones sugeridas** y **Publicaciones de baja calidad**](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

El resto de los privilegios, está descripto en [/help/privileges](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)